# Need suggestion about Facebook Connect

Tags: php, facebook

i try to use Facebook php sdk with js. I take access token with js and use it in php in order to get user.

My system is that If user connect my site first time, i stored it in my db . In second time, i will be familiar with him and connect with db check.

My question is that:

Think that : there is a user named USER and its FB id is 5555.

In my db, i have it, can i check it with my db ? What i want is that to retrieve user id from cookie and check with my db . Is it secure or not ? If not , i have to always do this operation with php and loss performance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use the Facebook JS SDK. Use the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/). Second of all, there is a LOT of user information you are not allowed to store in your own database per the FB Developer license agreement, so please read the agreement fully before storing sensitive information.

The secure way to do it is always get an access token from Facebook's Graph API. Once you have a token, then you can manipulate local user sessions and cookies as you see fit.

Comment: I'm using js sdk with php sdk? What is the disadvatages of this ? Why do you suggest Graph API?

Comment: Facebook suggests it. They're trying to migrate all devs off those SDK's and onto the Graph API. Read the docs man. The disadvantages of those SDK's are plentiful. They're not supported or documented well, they have a ton of stupid quirks, they're poorly written... the list goes on.

Comment: AlienWebGuy is confused.  The JavaScript SDK (built and maintained by Facebook) is a wrapper around the Graph API.  Feel free to use the JS SDK copiously in your app.  Here's a quote from offical Facebook documentation "The PHP SDK can work in conjunction with the JavaScript SDK to provide seamless session management across both the client- and server-sides of an app."  See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

Comment: @DMCS when they announced they were deprecating Facebook Connect, they also announced they were stopping support of those SDK's. Good to know they decided to keep them around I suppose, but I'll never trust their code again after being burned more than once from simple functions that didn't work as intended, with their forums saturated with questions such as the OP's being completely ignored by FB. Same old situation where a company gets too big and has tons of junior devs doing grunt work trying to make the dreams of a few quality tech leads come to life.

Comment: The old Javascript SDK was deprecated and they totally pulled the plug on it at the end of last month.  It was the old oauth version and not the oauth2 version.